# Python regex to convert particular pattern inside a file

Tags: python

Hi I"m looking to change below patterns inside a file:

```
input [15:0] A;
output [15:0] B;
inout     [4:0]   C;
input [3:0]     D;
inout [0:32] X;
output [5:2] Y;
```

to:

```
input A [15:0];
output B [15:0];
inout C [4:0];
input D [3:0];
inout X [0:32];
output Y [5:2];
```

What is the best way to achieve this using python regular expressions?

Here is what I wrote so far, it does the job but I think I could make it more efficient.
1.It does not convert multiple white spaces into 1. 
2.My regex only looks for the pattern  .*[po]ut. what is a good regex which can catch input/output/inout at the beginning of any line?
3. How can modify it to edit all files inside a given directory path?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1):
    line = re.sub(r'^(.*[po]ut)(\s+\[\d+:\d+])(\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*);',r'\1\3\2;',line.rstrip())
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = ["input [15:0] A;", "output [15:0] B;", "inout     [4:0]   C;", "input [3:0]     D;", "inout [0:32] X;", "output [5:2] Y;"]
import re
final_data = [re.sub("(?<=\w)\s+(?=\[)", " {} ".format(re.findall("[A-Z](?=\;)", i)[0]), i[:-2]) for i in s]
new_final_data = [re.sub("\s+$", ';', i) for i in final_data]
for i in new_final_data:
   print(i)
```

Output:

```
input A [15:0];
output B [15:0];
inout C [4:0];
input D [3:0];
inout X [0:32];
output Y [5:2];
```